# WinPE - Adding Custom Application to boot.wim or iso

Tags: winpe

Does anybody know how to add a customer exe into a ISO or boot.wim file with WinPE?

Please provide sample statements on how to add file and then launch it from WinPE Command Line.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you've installed the [Windows Automated Installation Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=696dd665-9f76-4177-a811-39c26d3b3b34&displaylang=en), you should be able to follow the directions in this page:

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709665(WS.10).aspx

It provides sample instructions for adding optional WinPE components to your WinPE image, as well as to add custom applications/files.